# Heston Model, differential equation of an evaluation of a generic derivative.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have this question.
Consider the Heston stochastic volatility model:

\begin{array}{rl}
dS_t = uS_t dt  + \sqrt{v_t} S_t dB_{1,t} \\
dV_t = \kappa(\theta - V_t)dt + \sigma\sqrt v_t dB_{2,t}
\end{array}

where $B^1, B^2$ are related Brownian motions. Find the differential equation of an evaluation of a derivative $f = f (t, S_t, v_t)$

As for the differential equation of evaluation of a generic derivative, from a payoff at maturity $ F (S_t, v_t) $, we define the price through the following equation:

$$f(t, s, v) = E^Q [e^{-r(T-t)}F(S_T,v_T)]$$

dividing by per $e^{rt}$ we get the discounted price:

$$\tilde{f}(t,s,v) = e^{-rt} f(t,s,v) = E^Q [e^{-r(T-t)}F(S_T,v_T)]$$

with relative dynamics: $d \tilde{f} = e^{-rt} df - re^{-rt} f dt \ $.

We now derive through the equations of the Heston model (in compact form according to the Q dynamics) using the Ito formula for a correlated two-dimensional process:

$ df = (\partial_{t}f + rS_t \partial_{S}f + \tilde{k} (\tilde{\theta} - v) \partial_{v} f+ \frac{1}{2} v_t S_t^2 \partial_{ss} f + \rho \eta S_t v_t \partial_{sv} f + \frac{1}{2} \eta^2 v_t \partial_{vv} f) dt + S_t \sqrt{v_t} \partial_s f dB_{1,t}^{\lambda} + \eta \sqrt{v_t} \partial_v f dB_{2,t}^{\lambda}$

Finally we get the condition of martingality:

$e^{-rt} (\partial_{t} f + rS_t\partial1_{s} f + \tilde{k} (\tilde{\theta} - v) \partial_{v} f + \frac{1}{2} v_t S_t^2 \partial_{ss} f + \delta \nu S_t v_t \partial_{sv} f + \frac{1}{2} \nu^2 v_t \partial_{vv} f)) - re^{-rt} f = 0$

The pricing of an generic derivate is correct?
Thanks for support.

Comment: The Heston model is well-known and so is the PDE the derivatives solve under this model. In fact Heston's original paper was mainly devoted to solving that PDE. Do you really want us to tell you if you have correctly re-derived Heston's PDE ? There must be dozens of books/papers/wikipedia articles and scripts that allow to to look that up.

Comment: Thanks Kurt for your support.

Comment: Also this might be a question better suited for this forum : https://quant.stackexchange.com/